# AngularJS Login example - amending for server authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, servicestack

I'm having trouble changing [Valerio Coltrè's github - angular login example](https://github.com/mrgamer/angular-login-example%5d) to work with my ServiceStack authentication.

I really like the authentication implementation Valerio has produced but he is using an `httpBackend` mock and intercepting the API GET and POST requests.  No matter what I've tried I cannot get it to play nicely with my ServiceStack API hosted at `/api`.

Has anyone done this before and got Valerio's solution to play nice with a REST service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved the problem but thought it worthwhile not deleting the question in case others have the same problem.  Also I do recommend others check out [Valerio's solution](https://github.com/mrgamer/angular-login-example) if anyone is looking for an angular authentication scaffold.

The answer kind of came to me whilst I posted the question:  I just removed the httpBackend factory and it's associated configuration as well as removed the injection of angular-login.mock.  It then stopped intercepting the http traffic and I was able to start authenticating against my web services.